# Magento 2: How to fetch UI Grid Component using data from external REST API

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, rest-api, ui-grid, data-provider

I wanna know how to fetch data into a UI Grid using external data retrieved from a REST API. Anyone has a step by step solution to achieve this?